# CSS - Flexbox/ Bootstrap STILL has horizontal scrolling HELP! D:

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS / HTML and I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.
I'm supposed to make it not have horizontal scrolling yet everything I tried failed me. I tried using {overflow: hidden} in the .body section but nothing. Can someone figure it out for me? I'm honestly lost lol

These are my codes:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-image: url(images/pattern4.jpg);
}


h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  margin: 0;
}

.work {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 -5px;
}

.item {
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
/* Adjusting Images! */

img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;

}

.logo {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  max-height: 50px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px groove grey;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-image: url(images/pattern5.jpg);
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.largeimage {
  display: block;
  max-width:100%;
  width: 97%;
  height: auto;
  border: 3px groove grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/* font sizes etc */

.headline {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px lightblue;
  border: 3px groove grey;
  padding: 8px 8px 7px 6px;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

.item2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px lightblue;
  border: 3px groove grey;
  padding: 8px 8px 7px 6px;
  border-radius: 60px;

}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 2px 1px grey;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: right;
    color: grey;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
}

p {
    font-size: 14px;
}



/* screen adjustments */
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .aboutme,
  .project1,
  .hobbies,
  .anime {
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        display: block;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        max-width: 100%;
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        margin: 20px 20px 20px 50px;
    }
    .item2 {
      margin: 20px 20px 20px 50px;
    }
    body {
      background-image: url(images/pattern2.jpg);
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 451px) {
  .aboutme,
  .project1,
  .hobbies,
  .anime {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px groove grey;
    padding: 8px 8px 7px 6px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-radius: 60px;
    background-image: url(images/pattern8.png);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 760px) {
  h1,
  h2 {
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
  html {
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
    margin-bottom:10%;
    margin-top:10%;
  }
  .largeimage {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    width: 1300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}

/* ipad / nexus responsive */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {
  body,
  html {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Konstantin Butko</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main2.css">
  </head>
  <!-- Body starts here -->
  <body>
   <div class="main1">
      <!--Row for logo and name-->
      <div class="header">
          <div class="logo1">
            <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
          </div>
          <div class="name">
            <h1>Konstantin Butko</h1>
            <h2>Front-End Ninja</h2>
          </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
     <!--Row for banner-->
      <div class="main">
         <div class="banner">
           <img class="largeimage" src="images/developer.jpg" alt="An image of a developer">
           <p class="headline">This is my Portfolio</p>
         </div>
     </div>
     <!--Row for featured work-->
      <div class="work">
          <div class="item">
            <img class="aboutme" src="images/aboutme.png" alt="About me"/>
            <p class="item2">About Me</p>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img class="project1" src="images/project.png" alt="Project 1"/>
            <p class="item2">Project 1</p>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img class="hobbies" src="images/hobbies.png" alt="My Hobbies"/>
            <p class="item2">My Hobbies</p>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img class="anime" src="images/anime.jpg" alt="Favorite Anime"/>
            <p class="item2">Favorite Anime</p>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <!-- FOOTER! -->
  <footer>
    Designed by Konstantin Butko.
  </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please only include essential information in your question's title -- this is how other users will stumble on your question. Please also reduce your question's example code to the minimal information that still exhibits the problem (this process might also help you narrow down the problem). I suggest you get inspiration from other successful questions on scrolling and overflow.

Comment: remove width:100% from body in css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three issues which I got...

**1**...apply `margin:0` to body which is by default `8px`

**2**...apply `box-sizing:border-box` to all using universal selector

**3**...remove `margin:0 -5px` from `.work`...it is taking extra space more than `100%`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-image: url(images/pattern4.jpg);
  margin: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  margin: 0;
}

.work {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}


/* Adjusting Images! */

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  max-height: 50px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px groove grey;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-image: url(images/pattern5.jpg);
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.largeimage {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 97%;
  height: auto;
  border: 3px groove grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/* font sizes etc */

.headline {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px lightblue;
  border: 3px groove grey;
  padding: 8px 8px 7px 6px;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

.item2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px lightblue;
  border: 3px groove grey;
  padding: 8px 8px 7px 6px;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 2px 1px grey;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: right;
  color: grey;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
}


/* screen adjustments */

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .aboutme,
  .project1,
  .hobbies,
  .anime {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    margin: 20px 20px 20px 50px;
  }
  .item2 {
    margin: 20px 20px 20px 50px;
  }
  body {
    background-image: url(images/pattern2.jpg);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 451px) {
  .aboutme,
  .project1,
  .hobbies,
  .anime {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px groove grey;
    padding: 8px 8px 7px 6px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 60px;
    background-image: url(images/pattern8.png);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 760px) {
  h1,
  h2 {
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
  html {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    margin-top: 10%;
  }
  .largeimage {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    width: 1300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}


/* ipad / nexus responsive */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  body,
  html {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>Konstantin Butko</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main2.css">
</head>
<!-- Body starts here -->

<body>
  <div class="main1">
    <!--Row for logo and name-->
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo1">
        <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
      </div>
      <div class="name">
        <h1>Konstantin Butko</h1>
        <h2>Front-End Ninja</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <!--Row for banner-->
    <div class="main">
      <div class="banner">
        <img class="largeimage" src="images/developer.jpg" alt="An image of a developer">
        <p class="headline">This is my Portfolio</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Row for featured work-->
    <div class="work">
      <div class="item">
        <img class="aboutme" src="images/aboutme.png" alt="About me" />
        <p class="item2">About Me</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="project1" src="images/project.png" alt="Project 1" />
        <p class="item2">Project 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="hobbies" src="images/hobbies.png" alt="My Hobbies" />
        <p class="item2">My Hobbies</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="anime" src="images/anime.jpg" alt="Favorite Anime" />
        <p class="item2">Favorite Anime</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <!-- FOOTER! -->
  <footer>
    Designed by Konstantin Butko.
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Bhuwan! Thank you so much. That actually solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

add overflow:hidden to body{} in css.

```
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
font-family: Roboto;
font-size: 12px;
background-image: url(images/pattern4.jpg);
overflow:hidden;}
```